# Redux store cannot update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a button trigger project create. What I want to do is when I click button, it will create a new project, and if there is no issue with product, it will go to the next step.

The dispatch on the click handler is working, I can see the redux runs the faild reducer if there is error, but the `projectData.successStatus` inside the handler cannot get the latest value which the the `successStatus` I want it to be `false`. It's still the previsous retrive project list success Status. So the `nextStep()` condition is not working.

Can someone help me find what's wrong?

This is the handler button:

```
const handleNextButton = useCallback(() => {
    if (newProjectName) {
        const newProjectWithProjectName = {
            ...newProject,
            projectName: newProjectName,
        }
        dispatch(createNewProjectReq(newProjectWithProjectName)) // create new project
        if (projectData.successStatus) {
            nextStep()
        }
    }
}, [newProjectName, projectData])
```

On the action, I have request, add, fail:

```
export const createNewProjectReq = (newProject) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: PROJECT_SENDING_REQUEST })
    try {
        const result = await createNewProject(newProject)
        const { project, message } = result.data.data
        dispatch({
            type: PROJECT_LIST_ADD,
            payload: { project, message },
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: PROJECT_REQUEST_FAIL, payload: error.data.message })
    }
}
```

Reducer switch:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case PROJECT_SENDING_REQUEST:
        console.log("PROJECT_SENDING_REQUEST")
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: true,
            successStatus: false,
        }
    case PROJECT_LIST_SUCCESS:
        console.log("PROJECT_LIST_SUCCESS")
        return {
            loading: false,
            projects: action.payload.projectListGroupByProjectId,
            successStatus: true,
            message: action.payload.message,
        }
    case PROJECT_LIST_ADD:
        console.log("PROJECT_LIST_ADD")
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            projects: [...state.projects, action.payload.project],
            successStatus: true,
            message: action.payload.message,
        }
    case PROJECT_REQUEST_FAIL: {
        console.log("PROJECT_REQUEST_FAIL")
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            successStatus: false,
            message: action.payload,
        }
    }
    default:
        return state
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

1. `handleNextButton` callback is synchronous code.
2. Reducer functions are also synchronous code.
3. State is generally considered `const` ***during*** a render cycle, i.e. it won't ever change in the middle of a render cycle or synchronous code execution.

Because of these reason the `projectData` state will not have been updated yet, the conditional check happens *before* the actions are processed.

## Solution

Since you really are just interested in the success of the action so you can go to the next step you can return a boolean value from the asynchronous action and await it or Promise-chain from it.

```
export const createNewProjectReq = (newProject) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: PROJECT_SENDING_REQUEST });
  try {
    const result = await createNewProject(newProject);
    const { project, message } = result.data.data;
    dispatch({
      type: PROJECT_LIST_ADD,
      payload: { project, message },
    });
    return true; // <-- success status
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PROJECT_REQUEST_FAIL, payload: error.data.message });
    return false; // <-- failure status
  }
}

...

const handleNextButton = useCallback(() => {
  if (newProjectName) {
    const newProjectWithProjectName = {
      ...newProject,
      projectName: newProjectName,
    }
    dispatch(createNewProjectReq(newProjectWithProjectName))
      .then(success => {
        if (success) {
          nextStep();
        }
      });
  }
}, [newProjectName, projectData]);
```

## Demo

Simple demo with click handler calling asynchronous function with 50% chance to succeed/fail.

[image: Edit redux-store-cannot-update]